# Redirect Console.Write of specific assembly

Tags: c#, .net, logging, reflection, log4net

In my C# application I am loading another assembly via reflection.

This other assembly writes to the console with the Console.Write functions.

I would like to redirect the output to a log4net appender for this specific assembly only. I would like all other assemblies to continue to output to the console.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't accepted the answer? (It seems like the answer covers what you asked for, then please accept the answer so the question does not show up under "unanswered".)

Comment: @flindeberg: i havent accepted it yet, because it doesnt work for my specific case, where i use log4net to write the logs. it produces lots of exceptions. i will put the details as a comment to the answer soon.

Answer (score 4):

1. `Console` class has static method `SetOut`, which redirects output to `StreamWriter` object.
2. Write your own `StreamWriter` extension class to redirect console output if assembly the same as you want. Just for exmple.

```
    public class Writer : StreamWriter
    {
        private readonly Assembly _assembly;
    
        private readonly StreamWriter _stdout;
    
        public Writer(Assembly assembly)
            : base(Console.OpenStandardOutput())
        {
            _assembly = assembly;
            _stdout = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
        }
    
        public override void Write(string value)
        {
            var st = new StackTrace();
            var curent = st.GetFrames();
            foreach (var frame in curent)
            {
                if (frame.GetMethod().Module.Assembly == _assembly)
                {
                    _stdout.Write("Redirected: " + value);
                    _stdout.Flush();
                    return;
                }
            }
    
            base.Write(value);
                this.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Threre may be some occasions, such as one assembly calls method, that writes to console from another assembly. I don't know how to predict this behavior.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, I was thinking about SetOut, but didn't came up to idea to filter based on assembly.

Comment: thx, but when i use this to log with log4net it creates this exception: `System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.`